# Find avg value from list having single element

Tags: python, list, average

The list contain single element with the array values. list is [array([[ 4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]])]. I need average of each value of tensors. For example here there are 2 tensor with 3 values so i need 3 values([7 8 9] in this case) with average of it. Find below code for reference.

```
import numpy
a=np.arange(1,13).reshape(2,2,3)
pt=[np.array([0,1]),np.array([1,1])]
list=[]
list.append(a[pt[0],pt[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(list, axis=1)[0]  # the list here refers to list you've created
```

This will return:

```
array([7., 8., 9.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(list[0], axis=0)
```

Bugs and cautions on your example though:

1. NEVER name your variable is `list`, `dict` or other built-in functions/types/keywords. Ideally use phrases relevant to the content, and meaningless varname is still better than overriding default functions.
2. `import numpy as np` rather than `import numpy`. Or you can simply `import numpy` and then write the lines afterwards with `numpy.array` instead of `np.array`.